# Pasting the result from an SQL statement into range of multiple cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array of SQL statements which i loop through, execute, obtain the results and paste.

Most of the statements return just the one value but one of the SQL functions returns four values. I would like to hold an array of ranges which I can just paste the results of each SQL function into.

What would be the correct code from the point I return the recordset, to the point which I paste the recordset data, which would work for 1 value results and 4 value results? Should I be using `Something = rs.getrows`?? and what paste statement should I use?

The four value-result will be pasted into a vertical range of four cells, named X.

EDIT, got this so far:

```
For i = LBound(SQLFunctionArray, 1) To UBound(SQLFunctionArray, 1)

    If UseCurrencyAsArg(i) = True Then
        SecondArg = Ccy
    Else
        SecondArg = FileName
    End If

    SQLFunctionToCall = SQLFunctionArray(i)
    Range(RangeForPasting(i)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(GetSQLData(COB, SecondArg, SQLFunctionToCall))

Next
```

but it doesnt work for the four-value SQL result. GetSQLData returns the `rs.getrows` array

Comment: Will each SQL statement always return the same number of rows?  If not, how do you know where each range should end?

Comment: @mellamokb I have created the ranges manually. All of the ranges, except one are just one cell. The other range consists of four vertical cells. See RangeForPasting(i)

Comment: I am thinking you will need to use a For loop and walk through the results of `rs.GetRows` to convert into a simple array.

Comment: Is there any way I could get the coordinates of a range, if the four-cell range could tell me it has four cells?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to flip your GetRows array:

```
Function TransposeGetRows(arr)
    Dim nr As Long, nc As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim arrOut()
    nr = UBound(arr, 2)
    nc = UBound(arr, 1)
    ReDim arrOut(0 To nr, 0 To nc)
    For r = 0 To nr
        For c = 0 To nc
            arrOut(r, c) = arr(c, r)
        Next c
    Next r
    TransposeGetRows = arrOut
End Function
```

Then put the array onto the sheet like this:

```
Range(RangeForPasting(i)).Resize(UBound(arr, 1) + 1, _
                                 UBound(arr, 2) + 1).Value = arr
```